# Using soundcloud as an audio file serve

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I would like to store samples for my iPhone application on soundcloud. This would enable me to  package a small binary and have the users download the sounds after installation.

I would make all of the sounds **publicly available for download** on soundcloud and once inside the app would connect to soundcloud and download the sounds.

Can I use the [soundcloud api](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference) to do this? The app user would not be signed in to soundcloud. Does this fall outside the terms of use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, yes, I don't see why this wouldn't be possible. As for Terms of Use, please refer to http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/terms-of-use and maybe https://soundcloud.com/terms-of-use

I personally don't think it's somehow a misuse, but don't take my word for it, verify it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that seems a reasonable use, but just be aware that tracks uploaded on free accounts have a limit of 100 downloads each.